# Possible to resize images coming back from an API call?

Tags: javascript, fetch

Im building an app, mobile first, and the data coming back from API
 is including large images that go off screen. Is it possible to set a size for all info coming back from the API so they are all centered and always fit inside the container?

[image]
[image]

Comment: set `img{max-width: 100%}` or use [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) to fit (not only images) inside their container.

Comment: You want to put height in a certain value ```img{height:200px;}``` and don't want to mention width. do this fro all images. It will give you what you expected